# SharePoint Library Query running very slow

Tags: performance, linq, sharepoint

We have a SharePoint query running on a library of maybe 500 documents to pull back the highest version of the published documents that are flagged as active (have active=true in the Active column).

This is taking way too long to run (about 3-5 seconds), which is frustrating the users.

What can be done to the query below to speed it up (I would hope for this to be virtually instantaneous!)

```
using (var site = new SPSite(Helpers.ConfigurationFile.SharePointUrl().ToString()))
{
    using (var web = site.RootWeb)
    {
        return
            web.Folders["Templates"].Files.OfType<SPFile>()
            .Where(file => file.Item.HasPublishedVersion)
            .Where(file => file.Item.Properties["Active"].ToString() == "true")
            .Where(file => file.Item.Versions.OfType<SPListItemVersion>()
                .Any(x => x.Level == SPFileLevel.Published))
            .Select(file => new LibraryItem(
                                      file.Item.UniqueId,
                                      file.Item.ID, 
                                      file.Item.Title, 
                                      Helpers.ConfigurationFile.SharePointUrl()
                                          .ToString().AddPathSegment(file.Url), 
                                      true, 
                                      float.Parse(file.MajorVersion.ToString() 
                                      + "." + file.MinorVersion.ToString())
                                      )

                    )
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A few points:

- Aren't the HasPublishedVersion and file.Item.Versions checks doing the same thing - checking whether a published version of the SPFile exists?
- The Any query on the SPListItemVersions will search them in order from Versions[0] to Versions[count - 1] which translates to 'newest to oldest' (since Versions[0] is the latest version in SP). If you think it's likely that your docs were published more frequently soon after creation than they have been in recent times, it'll possibly be faster to perform the same check by looping backwards through the collection (from oldest version to newest).
- You could index on the Active column.
- You can optimise it by performing part of the query using CAML (it's horrible, I know). I would try to delegate the SPFile fetching and Active checking to a CAML query, then do the rest of it using the object model. See [this link](http://e-junkie-chronicles.blogspot.co.nz/2011/04/splistitems-versus-spquery.html#!http://e-junkie-chronicles.blogspot.com/2011/04/splistitems-versus-spquery.html)
- If you do use CAML, PortalSiteMapProvider.GetCachedListItemsByQuery() might prove to be faster SPList.GetItems().

Comment: After turning off sections of the query, it is the line that references the file versions that's slowing the query (the LINQ gets turned into a separate query for each published doc).  I don't think I can access the file versions in CAML, so I think my best bet is to rewrite the code to just retrieve published docs and then get the specific version info once the user selects their document.    Thanks for replying!